# Slow startup due MachinePolicyApplication and PreShellInit

Tags: windows-7, boot

So far i have found only this two uncommon issues in
 Administartive tools / Event Viever / Applications and Services Logs /Microsoft / Windows / Diagnostics / Performance / Operational

```
Application of machine policy caused a slow down in the system start up process: 
 Name       :   MachinePolicyApplication
 Total Time     :   17079ms
 Degradation Time   :   16079ms
 Incident Time (UTC)    :   ‎2012‎-‎09‎-‎04T14:13:38.640400200Z
```

and

```
Application of user policy caused a slow down in the system start up process: 
 Name       :   PreShellInit
 Total Time     :   8696ms
 Degradation Time   :   6915ms
 Incident Time (UTC)    :   ‎2012‎-‎09‎-‎24T06:57:58.640400200Z
```

As you can see both applications takes approx 24s more than usually
How can I find source?

**EDIT**

Online I have found multiple sources about not having solid background wallpaper and some registry tweaks, but non of them seem to work. I had solid background before but now is removed, and i had solid wallpaper since first day of install, before noticing slow startup.
I am running up to date Win7 x64 system on SSD, intel-i7, 12GB ram.

Comment: make a boot trace with xbootmgr to see what is slow: http://www.msfn.org/board/index.php?showtopic=140247